# No direct way to access the meta page from the main page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-norepro, design

I don't see any link on the main Mathematica.SE page that leads directly to http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com. There is a panel in the top-right corner that links to "Hot Meta Posts", but this requires an additional click from one of those posts to the main meta page. I think there should be a clearer, straightforward and more visible way to access the meta page so more users are aware of its existance and purpose. I can speak from my own experience, it took me quite a while to notice it and start using it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the upper left corner, next to the recent achievements and the inbox there is a link list to all StackExchange sites.

[image: sshot]

Comment: Wow, I have actually never used this menu until now. Good to know.

Comment: @shrx I had the same problem with the (long abandoned) blog and although I used *SackExchange* menu every day, I never saw that the blog link is exactly there :-)

Answer (score 7):

@Karsten 7.'s answer made me look harder at the main site's menu bar and I actually found the second way to access the meta site - through the `help` menu:

[image: help menu link to meta]

Conveniently, you can also return back to the main site using the same menu while browsing the meta pages.